# Selecting entire Record for Distinct Column in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
[myTable]
ID
Name
HairColor
NumberOfPairsOfPants
```

I can easily get a list of HairColor with

```
SELECT DISTINCT HairColor FROM myTable
```

But I want the full contents the records  where the hair color is Distinct  (Yes the database table is denormalized/redundant so I don't get logic errors)

Pseudo code

```
SELECT DISTINCT HairColor,* FROM myTable
```

Syntax help!

Comment: When you say "I want the full contents the records where the hair color is Distinct," what do you mean?  I ask because SELECT DISTINCT HairColor FROM myTable doesn't tell you which hair colors ARE distinct, it tells you the distinct hair color values in your table. SELECT * FROM myTable would tell you the contents of all the hair colors returned by SELECT DISTINCT HairColor FROM myTable.

Comment: SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE HAIRCOLOR IS DISTINCT?

Comment: Okay, first off, the SELECT DISTINCT haircolor FROM myTable doesn't give you "Where haircolor is distinct." It gives you all the distinct hair colors. Kind of like "Distinct names in the room."  If there are two people named Sally, it'll give you one row for Sally. What you're looking for is a bit different. I'm answering the question below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first off, the `SELECT DISTINCT haircolor FROM myTable` doesn't give you "Where haircolor is distinct." It gives you all the distinct hair colors. Kind of like "Distinct names in the room." If there are two people named Sally, `SELECT DISTINCT name` would give you one row for Sally. What you're looking for is a bit different.

What you want to do is, first off all, determine which hair colors are distinct, ie, which ones occur only once. For that you will need

```
SELECT haircolor, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM myTable GROUP BY haircolor HAVING cnt > 1;
```

Once you've done that, you will want to join those results with your original table to get the entire rows associated with those hair colors, eg

```
SELECT a.* FROM myTable AS a
INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT SELECT haircolor, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM myTable GROUP BY haircolor HAVING cnt > 1) AS b
ON a.haircolor = b.haircolor
```